# Cover Browser Scrollbar With jQuery Scrollbar for Expanding Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

I have a menu that expands the entire size of the browser window, the demo can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeeYwX

Right now, *when* I add enough content to the div that a scrollbar is required, one is added to the div itself and the browser's scrollbar is still visible. The browser's scollbar then controls the content behind the div. Instead, I would like the DIV to cover the broswer's scrollbar like [the one on this website](http://www.apricotlaw.com/rank-for-car-accident-lawyer-in-your-city/) does when you click "Schedule a Consultation."

```
/* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

I have attempted a few options with overflow, but my options seem to be incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.